# Pandas read_csv does not get the last line in the CSV in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get all the data from a csv and break it down into columns using pandas read_csv

My code to read the csv is below. The purpose is to get the values for each column and store it in a variable (list).

```
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    test_type = df['test_type']
    tps = df['tps']
    mtt = df['mtt']
    mem = df['mem']
    cpu = df['cpu']
```

The CSV input file looks like this.

```
test_type,tps,mtt,mem,cpu
500_dr,255.240773286,934.362745167,22.5013831649,8.32771344429
1000_dr,212.425359712,2278.33653777,33.0718045361,6.50930517338
1500_dr,212.425359712,2278.33653777,33.0718045361,6.50930517338
```

I tried printing the list to see if I have captured the correct values by inserting this in my code.

```
    print test_type
```

Output:

```
0     500_dr
1    1000_dr
Name: test_type, dtype: object
```

It looks like it captures the values just fine except that the last row is not included when I print. How do I fix the code so that it captures the last row as well?

Comment: Can you include the code that prints the list?

Comment: It's right there in the question

Comment: your code runs fine on my MAC OSX. What version of pandas do you use? It looks like a bug from an older version. In which case, in your (hopefully linux) terminal, do `sudo apt-get update; sudo pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: I am using pandas-0.17.1 which is the latest version